# Simplest examples of different linear PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What is an example of each type of these PDEs?

(a) parabolic type with Neumann boundary conditions

(b) hyperbolic type with Neumann boundary conditions

(c) parabolic type with Dirichlet boundary conditions

(d) hyperbolic type with Dirichlet boundary conditions

Would an example of (a) be

$$u_t=u_{xx}$$
With boundary conditions
$$u_x(0,t)=u_x(L,t)=0$$ on the interval $0<x<L$?